# Get total size of a certain file type in the whole system

Tags: linux, size

Gm to all,
I need to find the sum of the total files of a certain type (for example pdf) in my entire linux machine (total file size, not the total occupied size).
For example i want to know the total size of all my pdf files or my jpg files starting from the root.
Of course, i need to use bash.
Any suggestion? (the only thing that i've learnt is that i should use -b option if using du).

Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `find` command: you can pass it a call to `du` with its `-exec` arg

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find`:

```
(echo 0; find / -name '*.pdf' -printf '%s+\n'; echo p) | dc
```

That gives a sum of the file size (not disk usage) of all the *regular* (excluding symlinks, directories, fifos...) `pdf` files.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 du -skc
```

Comment: That only works if the list of file is small enough that only one `du` invocation is needed.

Comment: For pdf files of type _directory_, that would count the disk usage of the file itself and also all the files under it.

Comment: Note that du reports disk usage, not file size. GNU du has a `--apparent-size` for file size.

Comment: Note that for files that have several links, that counts only one of them. With GNU du, you can disable that with `-l`

Comment: Note that if there's no pdf file, that will give you the disk usage of the current directory (GNU `xargs` has a `-r` option to avoid that, or you can use the  standard `-exec du... {} +` instead of the `-print0`/`xargs -0` GNU extension)